# Adobe Update framework for Flex Mobile does not work on desktop. Gives Error 1009

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flex-mobile

Following is output on my console:

[SWF] autoupdate.swf - 3,204,024 bytes after decompression
private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void
[ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Unhandled exception TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." errorID=1009]

my code is in Application Create Event (s:ViewNavigatorApplication)

```
protected function viewnavigatorapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    setApplicationVersion(); 
    appUpdater.delay = 1;
    appUpdater.isDownloadProgressVisible = true;
    appUpdater.isDownloadUpdateVisible = true

    appUpdater.isInstallUpdateVisible = true;
    appUpdater.isFileUpdateVisible = true;

    appUpdater.updateURL = "http://localhost/updater/update.xml";           
    appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false; // sajjad false initially 
    appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, onUpdate);
    appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);
    appUpdater.initialize();
}
private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void
{
    //Alert.show(event.toString());
    trace("private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void");
    trace(event);
}

private function onUpdate(event:UpdateEvent):void
{
    trace("private function onUpdate(event:UpdateEvent):void");
    appUpdater.checkNow(); // Go check for an update now         } 
}
```

I have added the 
     http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html

Can it be the case that i am trying to export the flex mobile application as desktop application and i need to create a desktop only project ?

Answer (score 0):

Its is better advice that you need to ***create a separate project for Mobile Application (ViewNavigatorApplication) and Desktop AIR(WindowedApplication)*** both are different. Air Application Updater Framework supports only for AIR(Desktop) applications, If you need Application updater for Native Application such as .exe or .dmg(MAC) you can use an external Native application updater library.

**AIR Application updater:**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff2.html#WS9CD40F06-4DD7-4230-B56A-88AA27541A1E

**Native Application Updater:**

http://www.riaspace.com/2010/08/nativeapplicationupdater-updater-for-air-apps-packaged-with-native-installers/
http://code.google.com/p/nativeapplicationupdater/

These **updater frameworks don't support Mobile Applications**. Since mobile applications (apk-Android and ipa-iOS) are native installers for mobile they have different update mechanism for that **you need to launch a new version in AppStore(iOS) or PlayStore(Android)**.

Refer this Docx for mobile Application update:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-77bd3ea112e2c0a7ed0-8000.html

Comment: 1. yes when the mobile apps are installed as native apps, this is ture, but when mobile apps are exported as desktop apps, then does this framework support?

2. When flex mobile app is epxorted as desktop app, it has extension as .air same exentension for pure desktop project. It means that underlying air framework should support autoupdate?

3. Error comes on method call  appUpdater.initialize()
Also the error gets caught in OnError method that already gets bound with appUpdaterObject.
Does this also mean that this is spark specific error and not autoupdate related..?

Comment: Correction: **(apk-Android and ipa-iOS)** instead of **(ipa-Android and apk-iOS)**